# Why does setTimeout use the old version of my function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, pass-by-reference

When I run the following code:

```
let fn = () => console.log('original fn was called');
fn();
setTimeout(fn.bind(this), 250);
setTimeout(() => fn(), 500);
setTimeout(fn, 750);
fn = () => console.log('updated fn was called');
```

This is outputted:

```
original fn was called
original fn was called
updated fn was called
original fn was called
```

I intuitively grok why the first two lines are outputted:

1. The function is immediately called.
2. The `bind` method is producing a new function from `fn`, therefore 'locking' in it's behavior.

However, I'm confused as to why lines 3 and 4 are different. I suppose in the 3rd case, the reference to `fn` is not being evaluated until the wrapping anonymous function is called. So it makes sense that it would utilize the updated implementation of `fn`. But in the 4th case, why doesn't setTimeout make use of the latest version of `fn`?

Comment: the closure does a delayed lookup by name, the rest eagerly have a reference to the original function object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable reference is evaluated only when the interpreter runs the statement. In 1, 2, and 4, you're referencing `fn` immediately, and using it somehow to pass to `setTimeout`:

```
fn();
setTimeout(fn.bind(this), 250);
setTimeout(fn, 750);
```

In 3, you're not referencing `fn` immediately - you're passing in a different anonymous function. Only when that anonymous function runs and the lines inside it get run do the references on those lines get checked by the interpreter to see what value the variable name points to.

> But in the 4th case, why doesn't setTimeout make use of the latest version of fn?

Because you referenced `fn` directly when calling `setTimeout`, just like in cases 1 and 2.

In the 3rd case, you have a function which *contains* a reference to `fn`, which will be evaluated when the anonymous function runs and the interpreter comes across that line - but not before.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it, thanks. So basically, in case #4, the `fn` is dereferenced immediately by setTimeout? That is, it isn't as if the setTimeout function holds on to the reference for 750ms. Instead, it immediately 'exchanges' it for the function object itself?

Comment: That's one way of looking at it. Variable names aren't passed to functions - *plain values* are passed to functions.

Answer (score 1):

The "fn" is just a reference to an object: first the "original" function; and in the end the "updated" function. In the third case the setTimeout called ()=>fn, and by that time fn had the "updated" value, but in the fourth case the "original" object was passed to setTimeout...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the summary:

```
let fn = () => console.log('original fn was called');
fn = () => console.log('updated fn was called');
```

When doing the above, you create two distinct functions in the memory. But - by the second statement, you lose any reference pointing to the first function.

Then,

```
setTimeout(() => fn(), 500);
```

.. you say execute after 500ms whatever referenced by `fn`. By this time the reference points to the "updated" function in your code.

```
setTimeout(fn, 750);
```

By above you give the reference of the first function to setTimeout. It stores this reference and executes after 750ms